# Mi pagina solo ejecuta una vez una insercion o edicion a la base de datos, si quiero ejecutar de neuvo me salta un error

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, servlets

espero que esten bien.

Tengo un problema con mi pagina web con java, jsp, servlets y jap. Cuando intento guardar un registro o editarlo se ejecuta muy bien la primera vez, pero si queiro volver a hacerlo me sale este error: /proyectoFinal/gestion_clientes/gestion_clientes/clienteNuevo.jsp

ESTA PAGINA ES PARA EDITAR UN REGISTRO Y REDIRECCIONA AL SERVLET

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Modificar Cliente</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <%@page import="proyectoFinal.clientes, proyectoFinal.DAOClientes" %>
    
    <% 
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        clientes cli = DAOClientes.obtenerId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    %>

    <div class = "container">
    
        <h1>Agregar Cliente</h1>
        <hr>
        <br/>
    
        <form action="ServletEditarCliente" method="POST" class = "form-control" style = "width: 500px; height: 450px">

            Id: 
            <input type="text" class = "form-control" name="id" value = "<%=cli.getId()%>"/>
            <br/>
            Nombre: 
            <input type="text" class = "form-control" name="nombre" value = "<%=cli.getNombre()%>"/>
            <br/>
            Apellido: 
            <input type="text" class = "form-control" name="apellido" value = "<%=cli.getApellido()%>"/>
            <br/>
            Dni: 
            <input type="text" class = "form-control" name="dni" value = "<%=cli.getDni()%>"/>
            <br/>
            Correo: 
            <input type="text" class = "form-control" name="correo" value = "<%=cli.getCorreo()%>"/>
            <br/>
            <!--Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono"/>
            <br/>
            Pais: <input type="text" name="pais"/>
            <br/>-->
            <input type="submit" value = "Registrar" class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"/>

        </form>
                
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

ESTE ES EL SERVLET

```
package pe.edu.universidad.uwin.pf.gestion.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import pe.edu.universidad.uwin.pf.gestion.dto.DTOClienteNuevo;
import pe.edu.universidad.uwin.pf.gestion_clientes.ServicioGestionClientes;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletEditarCliente
 */
@WebServlet("/gestion_clientes/ServletEditarCliente")
public class ServletEditarCliente extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    @Inject
    private ServicioGestionClientes servicio;
    
    public ServletEditarCliente() {
        super();
        
    }

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        System.out.println("POST usuario Nuevo");
        
        String strId = request.getParameter("id");
        String strNombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String strApellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
        String strDni = request.getParameter("dni");
        String strCorreo = request.getParameter("correo");
        
        DTOClienteNuevo dto = new DTOClienteNuevo();
        
        dto.setId(Integer.parseInt(strId));
        dto.setNombre(strNombre);
        dto.setApellido(strApellido);
        dto.setDni(strDni);
        dto.setCorreo(strCorreo);
        
        servicio.editarClienteJTA(dto);
        
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/clientes.jsp").forward(request, response); 
    }

}
```

ESTE CODIGO CONECTA EL SERVLET CON JPA

```
package pe.edu.universidad.uwin.pf.gestion_clientes;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import pe.edu.universidad.uwin.pf.gestion.dto.DTOClienteNuevo;
import proyectoFinal_jpa.Cliente;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ServicioGestionClientes
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ServicioGestionClientes {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "proyectoFinal_jpa")
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public ServicioGestionClientes() {
        
    }
    
    public int registrarClienteNuevoJTA(DTOClienteNuevo dto) {
        
        System.out.println("registrarClienteNuevo");
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        
        c.setId(dto.getId());
        c.setNombre(dto.getNombre());
        c.setApellido(dto.getApellido());
        c.setDni(dto.getDni());
        c.setCorreo(dto.getCorreo());
        
        em.persist(c);
        //Usuario uo = em.find(Usuario.class, 301);
        //System.out.println("usuario = " + uo.getNombre());
        return dto.getId();
    }
    
    public int editarClienteJTA(DTOClienteNuevo dto) {
        
        System.out.println("registrarClienteNuevo");
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        
        c.setId(dto.getId());
        c.setNombre(dto.getNombre());
        c.setApellido(dto.getApellido());
        c.setDni(dto.getDni());
        c.setCorreo(dto.getCorreo());
        
        em.merge(c);
        //Usuario uo = em.find(Usuario.class, 301);
        //System.out.println("usuario = " + uo.getNombre());
        return dto.getId();
    }

}
```

Cambie la redireccion despues de insertar o editar al index, pero al entrar de nuevo a la pagina de cliente sale el mismo error.

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Lecturas sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> aquí obtienes tu primera medalla al estar informado por el funcionamiento/dinámica del sitio, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 -> mis recomendaciones para formular preguntas con altas chances de obtener respuesta(s). 3. ¿Qué dice el error y dónde está el error(especificar línea y archivo)? Saludos.